# Proper punctuation with two alternatives related to an infinitive

Tags: пунктуация

In the text below, do I need a comma right after the word "неправильно"?

> И здесь я вовсе не спрашиваю о том, правильно ли это или **неправильно**
>   отчитывать детей при всех, я просто хочу узнать, как у вас обходятся с
>   детьми.

Comment: I think No, but I'm not sure. If I'll write this text to somebody of my colleagues, I will not use the comma.

Comment: If there is no ambiguity (and there's no), I prefer do not use a comma, regardless of rules. But it is only IMHO.

Comment: Guess, there's no clause that requires to be separated by comma.

Comment: You can but try [`правильно ли [0...10 words] неправильно`](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%EF%F0%E0%E2%E8%EB%FC%ED%EE&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%EB%E8&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod3=sem&sem-mod3=sem2&flags2=&m3=&parent3=0&level3=0&min3=1&max3=10&lex3=%ED%E5%EF%F0%E0%E2%E8%EB%FC%ED%EE&gramm3=&sem3=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags3=&m2=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crux is *это*. With it, you have a complete clause in `правильно ли это или неправильно`, and you need punctuation where it ends. I'd say, though, that a dash would fit much better than a comma.

If you lose *это*, and possibly *ли* along with it, and are left with `правильно или неправильно отчитывать детей при всех`, no punctuation is needed, since the verb phrase about telling children off becomes the subject.

Comment: So, if I keep это and  ли, then I need comma, right?

Comment: @brilliant You need *something*, and, like I said, I think it should be a dash. A comma would look somewhat random there, or else mark the sentence for a kind of brooding intonation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this comma.

The rule applied here (useful with any parenthetical clause or word): if you can withdraw the part of sentence between commas and the sentence will be still meaningful then commas are needed.

Check - the sentence without the part at question loses any sense:

> И здесь я вовсе не спрашиваю о том, отчитывать детей при всех, я просто хочу узнать, как у вас обходятся с детьми.

Similar example where commas are needed (from [here](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum_attach2/)):

> Случайно появляется газ или нет, связан ли он с циклонами, а значит, можно ли по этому признаку прогнозировать – вопрос требует выяснения.

Comment: I'm sorry but your answer is wrong. You seem to have missed the *это*. It's the difference between `что за человек такой Иванов` and `что это за человек такой — Иванов`.